# PostgreSQL use of CurrentDatabase to set variable

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use below syntax to set variable under HDB DATABASE.

```
ALTER DATABASE HDB SET "abc.var1"='aaa';
```

However I need to provide database name for this. If I want to use CURRENT database instead.

There is a method in PostgreSQL which actually returns current database name: **current_database()**,  but even below example is also not a valid one.

```
ALTER DATABASE current_database() SET "abc.var1"='aaa';
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that:

```
do
$$
begin
  execute format('alter database %I SET %I = %L', current_database(), 'abc.var1', 'aaa');
end;
$$
```

Using parameters and the placeholders `%I` and `%L` for the variable name and value avoids nesting quotes in the call to `format()` and properly deals with quoting.

Comment: Is there simpler possible way? I mean without using dynamic SQL ?

Comment: @Pratik: no there isn't

Comment: Noted with Thanks :)